# What's the best way to communicate with a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I need to be able to get the URL from the active tab in Firefox.  DDE doesn't work with multiple instances so I was thinking that I could build an addon that sets a global atom or something.

I also thought that maybe I could use the clipboard, but I don't want to overwrite any existing text and custom clipboard types doesn't seem to be supported.

I don't want to resort to writing a file just to do simple IPC...so before I do it...is there a better choice for something so simple.

thanks

Comment: You could do something really silly like write out the current URL to a file every time it changes and read that file from the other process.

Comment: You can find solution on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582607/find-url-of-current-tab-making-a-firefox-browser-add-on

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of communicating from an application to a Firefox add-on is via TCP sockets. You create an [nsIServerSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIServerSocket) instance, call `init()` on it and then `asyncListen()`. When the application connects to your socket the method [onSocketAccepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIServerSocketListener#onSocketAccepted%28%29) of your listener gets called and you get an [nsITransport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITransport) instance that you can read data from or write to (use [NetUtil.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm) to read from the input stream asynchronously).

For a relatively simply example implementation see [mozSocket.jsm](http://hg.instantbird.org/experiments/file/d4326febed80/modules/mozSocket.jsm) (not using `NetUtils.jsm` for reading data).

Comment: Using TCP sockets just to get the URL for the currently active tab sounds like overkill.  Since I'm not a Java or Firefox guy, it looks like I'm going to have to go 'hack' and just write the URL to a file or something else as ugly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its the best way, but I think using [MozRepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki) will help you.
MozRepl will make you able to interact with firefox through telnet.

```
% telnet localhost 4242
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Welcome to MozRepl.

repl> content.location.href
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525428/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-with-a-firefox-addon"
repl>
```

After installing MozRepl, You can use this little ruby script to get the url of currently opend tab.

```
require 'net/telnet'

t = Net::Telnet.new('Port' => 4242)
t.waitfor(/repl.*>/)
puts eval(t.cmd("content.location.href").split[0])
t.close
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this has been implemented in Firefox yet or if it's still in the idea phase:
[Mozilla Notifications API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Notifications/Push/API).

Google has GCM for Chrome extensions.