# Can I use android intent from firefox extention?

Tags: android, firefox-addon

I need send some data from firefox extension to native android application. How can I use intent for this? Is it an api in firefox for this action?
Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Is this from the android version of firefox?

Comment: Sorry! Android 4.0.3 and firefox  15.0.1 (for android). I need send data from firefox to another android application.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible using as an example the code in this [add-on](https://github.com/cscott/intent-addon)

Its done in a very neat way using JNI to access the Android intents Java classes via Firefoxes C++ code.

Comment: Struggling with the section "hacky way to get activity context" in the add-on main.js code (causes firefox mobile crash). What is the reason?

Comment: This is super cool, do you have any other work based on this Maks or @mmh to share?

Comment: Heres a copy paste example that works: https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-for-android-addons/blob/355f9a01464a0794c1084e8fdbab92c58503f49a/snippets/jni.js#L23-L44

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Firefox for Android consists of two parts: the Gecko browser engine (native binary, same as for the desktop Firefox) and the Java-based user interface (Android-specific). The two parts are largely independent and communicate via messaging. Extensions run in Gecko, only the Java-based part can use intents however. I looked at the messages that these two parts can exchange and they are all very specific and related to particular browser actions, nothing that would allow using a generic intent.

If the native application is already running you might be able to [communicate via TCP sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525428/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-with-a-firefox-addon/8531503#8531503). Either the extension or the native application would need to open a server socket on a well-known port that the other party would connect to.

Comment: Thanks! Is there ability send data in command line params? For example, I will send my data like this - 
`target_programm my_data_sting`
Will it work if android application started already?

Comment: @izumeroot: Don't know, try it? Starting a process should work on Android exactly the same as on desktop. What happens if you start a second instance of your application normally depends on your application - it needs to find the first instance and communicate back to it.

Comment: A communication with first instance i can do via sockets also? Then I don't see sence in  command line param.